# Why the pagination of footable is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I'm trying to implement `FooTable-2` in my project, but for some reason I can't get the pagination working.

I'm following [THIS](http://www2.gsu.edu/~polmfh/database/FooTable/demos/paging.htm#docs) tutorial and here is what I have so far as a table code:

```
<div id="mainContent">
   <div id="allTrackersDiv" style="display: none;">
      <label><b>Active Trackers</b></label>
      <table class="activeTrackersTable" id="allTrackersTable" 
         data-page-navigation=".pagination">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th> ID </th>
               <th> col 1 </th>
               <th> col 2 </th>
               <th> col 3 </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody data-bind="foreach: trackersObjArray">
            <tr data-bind="click: test">
               <td><span data-bind="text: tId"></span></td>
               <td><span data-bind="text: tname"></span></td>
               <td><span data-bind="text: pname"></span></td>
               <td><span data-bind="text: tcreate"></span></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="4">
                  <div class="pagination"></div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tfoot>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the paging is not working. I have 22 records in my table and it is supposed to start paging after the 10th record

Here is how it looks:

[image: Cropped image]

What am I missing here? At my point of view everything looks pretty fine. What am I missing, I really can't understand my mistake.

Comment: You need to post your JavaScript too. And a fiddle would also help.

Comment: The headline "Why the paging is not working?" does not describe your issue. Whenever posting, make sure you try to explain your problem in a few words... just saying.

Comment: Did you try adding `data-page-size="10"` explicitly? In case there is an issue with default?

Comment: @LittleSuzy yes I tried it. :)

Comment: That didn't work, too? @Slim

Comment: @LittleSuzy No luck so far.

Comment: Are you adding data to table dynamically? [this might be issue](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/issues/145)

Comment: @LittleSuzy It worked! Would you place a quick answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Done @Slim :) congrats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try mentioning

```
data-page-size="10"
```

explicitly.

And if that doesn't work, may be issue is due to dynamic data being added to footable.

Use

```
$('#myTable').append(html).trigger('footable_redraw');
```

So that footable will be redrawed and size limit will be applied.

Reference links: [Footable data page size not respected](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/issues/145) and
[Other issues due to dynamic data in footable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295763/issue-in-footable-while-adding-dynamic-data)

Comment: If append(html) does not work try (this.html) so the code will now be:
$('#myTable').append(this.html).trigger('footable_redraw');